# Megilat Ester linguistics - why inline translations?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, language

M"E is full with "inline" translations or clarifications from Hebrew to Parsi and vice verse, for example:

- פור הוא הגורל
- הֲדַסָּה הִיא אֶסְתֵּר
- בחודש השנים עשר הוא חודש אדר

This is pretty unusual I think for the Holy Writings. Why would the Sages use such phrasing?

Comment: היהודים הפרוזים הישבים בערי הפרזות. בחדש הראשון הוא חדש ניסן.

Comment: I think each of these points has its unique reasoning. In your examples: The 2nd point is  prob. to point out her Hebrew name b/c she was Jewish and Megillah wanted to tell you how she was able to hide being Jewish, so she had a Persian name, so no one suspected she was Jewish. As for the months - perhaps at the time of the writing, few people outside the Babylonian empire might have known what the name of the 1th month (etc.) was called. Or, it may have been to clarify / coordinate those who might have thought that Adar was the 6th month.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.9.9?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK This is different as those are not foreign words - just different types of prophecy - נבואה - from ביאה and רואה from ראיה.

Comment: @AlBerko It’s a ‘translation’ of an archaic Hebrew word to a word that the audience is familiar with.

Comment: @JoelK That's weird to call the Torah archaic "וְלֹא־קָם נָבִיא עוֹד בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל כְּמֹשֶׁה"

Comment: @AlBerko No, it’s רואה that is archaic. The pasuk is explaining that when Shaul is looking for a רואה he means what is now called a נביא.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first phrase you question:

הִפִּיל פּוּר הוּא הַגּוֹרָל , in [Parshas Beshalach, The Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.16.15?lang=bi&with=Rashbam&lang2=he#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D) specifies that the origin of the word is Persian, and the reason the holiday is called Purim and why the megillah itself translates "pur" from persian to the Hebrew "goral" is because the locals understood what "pur" and "purim" meant, and the translation of it into hebrew was for future generations to understand why we call this holiday "purim'.